# Make roots fit fractions size with nccmath package

Tags: sqrt, nccmath

Sometimes I use the `nccmath` package to resize equations, mainly resizing fractions with the `\mfrac`command, but I have an issue with roots that contain fractions:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \sqrt{\frac{A}{B}} \qquad \sqrt{\mfrac{A}{B}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I make roots fit the `\mfrac` heigth?

Comment: You're being unlucky: the radical is only available at some fixed sizes, until its right side becomes vertical and can be sized at will. Here `\mfrac{A}{B}` triggers the same size for `\frac{A}{B}`. If you try `\sqrt{\mfrac{a}{b}}` you'll get a smaller radical. With `\medmath{\sqrt{\frac{A}{B}}}`, a scaled down font for the radical is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `\medmath` command:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \sqrt{\frac{A}{B}} \qquad \sqrt{\mfrac{A}{B}}\qquad\medmath{\sqrt{\frac{A}{B}}}%
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Screenshot from the [`nccmath` manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/nccmath).*
[image]

Comment: +1: I added a screenshot from the manual that explains the command - hope that is ok.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: It's fine for me. Thanks! I must say I tend to think all users take a look at the packages documentations, which isn't always the case, of course.

Comment: That was my first thought after seeing your answer (--> RTFM :)).

Comment: I guess this abbrevaiation is for the ‘FABULOUS Manual’? ;o)

Comment: Just to clarify, I took a look to the `nccmath` manual and I knew about the `\medmath` command... but I'm looking for a more general solution. To resize equations (I'm a typesetter) I use something like `\renewcommand{\frac}{\mfrac}` for the target equation. The solution you proposed is right but a little bit overkill for my purposes. Anyway thanks!